# How can one generate Clover-compatible (Bamboo) xml which includes coverage data for python unnittest?

Tags: python, nose, bamboo, clover

NoseXUnit used to be able to generate Clover-compatible xml files, but it is no longer maintained, and does not work with recent versions of Nose.

How can one generate Clover-compatible (Bamboo) xml which includes coverage data nowadays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge nose can only output Cobertura format. This is done by passing `--with-coverage` and `--cover-xml` [nose coverage options](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/cover.html). You can then use [coverage2clover](https://github.com/tumb1er/bamboo-build-tools) utility to convert coverage.py xml report to Atlassian Clover test report format understood by Bamboo.

Comment: Tried. It generates xml output quite different from what Clover expects.

Comment: I added conversion instructions, did it work for you @tarnay-kálmán?

Comment: Yes, it worked, kinda. The only things Clover ended up displaying were 2 charts about "Coverage History" and "Lines of Code History". I ended up generating html reports using nose during the build, and setting the "Clover Report (System)" artifact to copy that, and now above the charts the "View latest Clover HTML report" link opens  nice nose-generated reports.

Comment: Also check out this PyPI package as another alternative to covert to Clover format: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cobertura-clover-transform

Comment: @TarnayKálmán is correct, see the official response here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/280592/answers/2593337/comments/36115268